# Windows 2008 Security Tips

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

I would like to setup a new dedicated server with the following:

- Windows Server Standard 2008 64bit Edition
- Plesk control panel

Questions:

Anyone know of a thorough tutorial on securing/optimizing a Windows 2008 server (even with Plesk) for a shared hosting environment?

Other ?'s:

Considering Plesk's rip-off pricing, any free and quality alternatives to their products?

- plesk dr.web antivirus
- acronis trueimage backup
- plesk powerpack (I guess $24.99/mo lease isn't too horrible)

Thank you.

PS: I basically want to replicate a Cpanel shared/reseller hosting environment, but with Plesk since Cpanel for Windows is not yet available and been delayed forever.

Comment: You should write your question better...

Comment: What do you mean? How do you not comprehend my question?

Comment: I mean, "Who kills and destroys"? Are you really looking for points on securing your Win2008? How does one know that from the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some references,

- [Secure Windows Server 2008](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548366(WS.10).aspx) -- TechNet
- [Windows Server 2008 Security Guide](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fb8b981f-227c-4af6-a44b-b115696a80ac&displaylang=en) from the Microsoft site
- [WS2008: Windows Service Hardening](http://blogs.technet.com/askperf/archive/2008/02/03/ws2008-windows-service-hardening.aspx) TechNet blogs Feb/2008
- [Windows Server 2008 Security Compliance Management Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc514539.aspx)

There is also an Elsevier book: [SECURING WINDOWS SERVER 2008](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/bookdescription.cws_home/714767/description)

Answer (score 1):

Cheaper than plesk... what about [DotNetPanel](http://www.dotnetpanel.com/)?

BTW, i hate panels, i feel that are so useless (unless you are an hosting provider)

Comment: DNP looks very ugly and a bit too bare. Tried the demo.

I *am* using this for web hosting purpose (reselling).

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft hosting partner site has the reference secure architecture, you should have been pointed to that when you signed your SPLA agreement. (note that it's almost required to follow that architecture- you'll end up 90% there anyway just by securing 2008 properly). Dotnetpanel is OK if you have just basic needs, plesk is a notch above that with hostingcontroller being the one I've seen with the most flexability and wide range of product support.

Comment: Why do you assume I signed up for their spla??? I never said that, what's with jumping to conclusions?

Comment: I assumed you signed up for SPLA because you said you were doing webhosting, signing up is required to become a windows webhoster.